# Change currency formatting globally for all currency fields on all forms

Tags: ms-access-2007, currency, currency-formatting

I just built a database system with a few forms. The forms had currency fields. I have a US English language setting in Windows and an English Access 2007. So I figured that was why I got the $x,xxx.yy format. I continued and finished the system; I had only set the Format to Currency, so I figured the actual formatting was elsewhere.

The database fields, too, are set simply to Currency.

Now this is to be used on a Swedish machine. How do I set the global currency format, so that they will not display currencies in the $x,xxx.yy format, without having to edit all the fields on each form?

(That is, they should still have Format: Currency, and the exact number stored in the database and shown in the field should simply be displayed in the correct Swedish format.)

Answer (score 1):

This code **has not been thoroughly tested** but it may be of some help to you. Make a backup of your database before trying it out.

Its intent is to replace the hard-coded `Format` properties like `$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)` that Access has (surreptitiously) stored with the generic value `Currency`.

```
Sub TweakCurrencyFormats()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field
Dim ao As AccessObject, frm As Form, ctl As Control
Set cdb = CurrentDb

Debug.Print "Processing tables..."
For Each tbd In cdb.TableDefs
    For Each fld In tbd.Fields
        If fld.Type = 5 Then  '' Currency
            Debug.Print "[" & tbd.Name & "].[" & fld.Name & "]"
            fld.Properties("Format").Value = "Currency"
            fld.Properties("CurrencyLCID").Value = 1053  '' Swedish
        End If
    Next
    Set fld = Nothing
Next
Set tbd = Nothing

Debug.Print "Processing forms..."
For Each ao In CurrentProject.AllForms
    If Not ao.IsLoaded Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm ao.Name, acDesign
    End If
    Set frm = Application.Forms(ao.Name)
    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        If ctl.Properties("ControlType").Value = 109 Then  '' text box
            If Left(ctl.Properties("Format").Value, 1) = "$" Then
                Debug.Print "[" & ao.Name & "].[" & ctl.Name & "]"
                ctl.Properties("Format").Value = "Currency"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set ctl = Nothing
    Set frm = Nothing
Next
Set ao = Nothing

Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[It's impossible.](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-44.html)

I will leave this up for a bit. If you can provide a clever solution to not have to manually edit all forms, I will happily accept yours instead of this. :)